# What is `--loc=surv` in git?

Tags: git

What is `--loc=surv`? I can't find any definition for it anywhere.

For getting the contribution stats in a git repo, I found [git-fame by casperdcl](https://github.com/casperdcl/git-fame) on GitHub. It offers a chart of contributions per contributor.
I don't consider the sum of insertions and deletions in git a good scale. but [git-fame](https://github.com/casperdcl/git-fame) offers another option called "surviving lines-of-code" (`--loc=surv`). but I don't understand what it is.
When should I use it? Is it a better scale to count contributions?

Comment: You should read the README in the repository that you linked yourself, it explains nicely what `--loc` (line of code)'s three values does.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Github, so I've removed that tag. It doesn't even have much to do with git itself, it's just an option supported by the specific script you've found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--loc=surv` means "Surviving Lines of Code", meaning the code that currently exists, not counting the deletions (`del`) or past insertions (`ins`).

#### The following was answered by the developer of [`git-fame`](https://github.com/casperdcl/git-fame), [casperdcl](https://github.com/casperdcl) on [this issue](https://github.com/casperdcl/git-fame/issues/75#issuecomment-1074422321):

> Does it just count the last revision on that line?

`--loc=surv` indeed counts "just the last revision on that line." It may be useful to also include `-M` and `-C` options.

> looking for the best way to measure how much I have to pay my devs.

Here be dragons  ... the `--cost` options can guesstimate hours & months using different models as per https://github.com/casperdcl/git-fame#faqs - but note:

- there's no way to distinguish between refactoring (presumably high value) & reformatting (presumably lower value)
- generated code (e.g. `package-lock.json`) is probably better measured by number of commits, while functional code (e.g. `train.py`) is probably better measured by number of lines
- deletions `--loc=del` (removing bad code) and past insertions `--loc=ins` (no longer surviving lines which nevertheless influenced the ideas behind the current code) could also both be useful
- one line of code may be more valuable than 100. Quality can only be measured by a human
- reviewing other people's code may be valuable but doesn't show up in Git history
- ... the list of caveats goes on

I would at best use `git fame` as one of many many ways to help gauge the true value of contributions. One possible strategy is getting people to review each other's work if you feel incapable of reviewing it yourself. I would not suggest paying people solely based on number/rate of commits/lines.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is not "in git". It is a feature added to [`casperdcl/git-fame`](https://github.com/casperdcl/git-fame) in its release [v1.14.0 Q4 2020](https://github.com/casperdcl/git-fame/pull/51), and [commit 2d34d84](https://github.com/casperdcl/git-fame/commit/2d34d847e74357834f209c9dbe7bf559b8f85f46).

Any executable named `git-xxx` (in `$PATH`) can be called with `git xxx`, giving the illusion that `xxx` is a Git command. It is not.

Second, as illustrated in [issue 59](https://github.com/casperdcl/git-fame/issues/59#issuecomment-886094448), it is the default option.

> I didn't expect any differences between `git-fame` and `git-fame --loc=surviving` - and there are none.

Third, it does measure lines which are still there between commit (which have not been added or removed), which allows to:

- associate options like `--ignore-rev` or `--ignore-revs-file=<f>` (valid only for surviving lines),
- exlude options like `--cost` (time cost in person-months (COCOMO) or person-hours (based on commit times), which is only based on delta (lines added/removed)

Comment: If it does measures lines which are still there between commits, how is the contribution on that single line counted? Is it counting the last rivision on that line? Afterall, Is it a better way to count contribution (like to pay the devs)?

Comment: @Movahhedi Contribution (and associated cost) means lines have changes (added/remove/modified).